# deleted my home folder, how to get it back?

Tags: 11.04, data-recovery, home-directory

I stupidly deleted my home folder in Natty. It's still in the trash but I cant get there to undo. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Searching I couldn't find any solutions because I don't think anybody else did that yet. I can only use the command line at this stage, and I'm noob at that.

Comment: err.. it might actually be gone. You see, trash is stored in /home/<yourname>/.trash. If you're home directory is gone, the trash went with it. How did you delete it? EDIT: apparently .trash is out dated, 1 sec

Comment: 1 method I think that will work: use a live CD. Then you can use this to go to command line and move the files back from trash to your home.

Comment: Add result of command ls /home .Maybe extundelete will help, http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/. Just dont use that disc if you want your files restored.

Comment: thanx, will try try all suggestions just now, what happened is that I saw a file in my home dir called windows, opening it I saw a complete copy of my home dir.It was an ordinary file between my other files not hidden not ./ so I thought this is strange an I deleted It, and that is where my woes began,

Comment: Logging in I get this:-1st screen:- could not update ICEauthority File/home/user//.ICEauthority.  2nd screen:- There is a problem with the configuration server (usr/lib/libconf2-4/gconfig-sanity-check-2exited with status 256) 3rd screen _:- nautilus could not create the following required folders:/home/user/desctop/home/user/nautilus, Before running nautilus, please create these folders, or set permissions such that nautilus can create them. Some how I got a file list and saw my home dir is still there can remember how but I think It was with "ls" command. Hope this help you people a bit more.

Comment: ls :- say "no such file or directory"

Comment: how can I move file back from trash with command line? what is the command please?

Comment: "restore-trash windows" doesn't help

Comment: What will happen if I have to re-install natty, will I still be able to recover some of the lost files with a program like extundelete or is it gone for ever?

Comment: Before running nautilus, please create these folders, or set permissions such that nautilus can create them.

Comment: "Before running nautilus, please create these folders, or set permissions such that nautilus can create them".  How can I set permissions from command line that nautilus can do that?

Comment: Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the bootable CD?  Rinzwind is correct.  One way of doing this is by using a live CD.  Boot the OS, mount the disk, and navigate via Nautilaus or a terminal to /media//user/.local/share/Trash  Locate your data and move it back.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same three problems

1st screen: could not update ICEauthority File/home/user//.ICEauthority.

It's possible that you were using a graphical application running as root that has updated your ICE Authority file with root permissions.

Try the following in a terminal session:

> sudo chown $USER:$USER .ICEauthority
>
> > sudo chmod 0644 .ICEauthority

I tried this I was able to  get out of this issue.

2nd screen: There is a problem with the configuration server (usr/lib/libconf2-4/gconfig-sanity-check-2exited with status 256)
nautilus could not create the following required folders:/home/user/desctop/home/user/nautilus

Try executing this in terminal:

> sudo chmod 1777 /tmp

I hope this may solve the issue. I haven't tried this.

Answer (score -1):

It does not need to use Live CD, simply do a `cp` command or `nautilus /path/to/trash` and do copy with the GUI.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem helpful. Explaining what is the exact path to trash would be important.